# Splitting a line according to keyword (with spelling mistakes)

Tags: c++, parsing

I have an input text file containing information (Age, Name, Job, Salary...) on 3 individuals. Now those keywords could be misspelled. I have to parse the three lines and be able to compare them with a template later on.

My question is just on how I should approach this. I started by parsing each line into a `vector<string>` but I don't know how I can then look at each element of the vector and read the different pieces of information even if they contain spelling mistakes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Name: Kevin, Jeb: Accountant, Yers of Experience: 5, Salery: 10000
Name: Susan, Job: Restaurant Owner, Years of Experience: 5, Salary: 14000
```

**Side Note**: The information in each line do not have to be in this order, each line can display them in a random order.

Comment: Nice question. But how does your file look like: 1 field per line? What separator btw field and value ?

Comment: Normally this would be very easy, however the requirement to recognize misspellings turns an easy assignment to a very hard assignment, at least if you want to be able to be able to recognize general spelling errors and not just from a list of common misspellings. You might want to read about [approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).

Comment: Can typos be of any kind, or just the most common ones (e.g. hitting "i" instead of "o")? Is there a limit for mistyped characters in a word?

Comment: Typos can be of two types: Deletion (i.e. Titl instead of Title) and Substitution (i.e. experiance instead of experience).

Comment: I'm working (professionally) on a software that does "fuzzy" string recognition. The code for "properly" handling spelling mistakes is several hundred lines long...

Comment: I'm not looking for something extremely professional or foolproof. There are like 2-3 spelling mistakes in the whole file, so maybe I can use || operator to check against those?

Comment: Can `,` or `:` be a typo?

Comment: What if a very similar property name is added? For comparison: When parsing XML with for instance `XmlSerializer` it will throw an exception when the XML cannot be interpreted. Have you thought about, instead of allowing these spelling mistakes, instead throwing an "unrecognized property" or something similar for the misspelled words?

Comment: If you know the place of the keys (i.e. Name is before Job which is before Salary), it's just a matter of reading them in sequence and you won't have to care about spelling errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need the *result*, not the *process*, the most easy way would be the most straightforward way. You are saying that

> Typos can be of two types: Deletion (i.e. Titl instead of Title) and Substitution (i.e. experiance instead of experience).

I assume that each typo type (pun intended) can only occur once per word (otherwise the task makes little sense). So here is your line:

```
Name: Susan, Job: Restaurant Owner, Years of Experience: 5, Salary: 14000
```

After splitting it by the commas, you will get 4 parts:

```
Name: Susan
Job: Restaurant Owner
Years of Experience: 5
Salary: 14000
```

Now, each part has a "key" and a "value", it's also easy to separate them by splitting by ":". The values are of two fundamental types: integers for salary and years or experience, and strings for name and job.

Take the ones that have integers as values. Between them, it's easy to tell years of experience and salary apart, because "years of experience" even with typos is a much longer string than "salary".

Now take the ones with string values. This one is harder because you can't use the key's lengths to tell keys apart. However, the words "Name" and "Job" do not share any characters. So if a key contains at least two characters from the word "Name", then it's the "Name" key, and vice versa.